# I want to make static IP on my tablet using usb-c to ethernet port

Tags: gateway, usb-c

I have Huawei Meta Pad t10s tablet & usb-c to pd rj45 adapter to connect it to ethernet not WIFI and it connect to internet automatically but I want to connect to server with another Gateway and need to enter static IP but can't find the way in the software of the tablet.
can any one help me to find solution to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the router/DHCP server, you can do a DHCP reservation on the MAC of the USB to ethernet adapter.  This means that even though the port is set to DHCP, it will always get the same address.